# Tayammum and gusl doubt

Tags: ghusl, tayammum

I've masterbated at night and I can't do gusl now as I'm scared of my parents. can i do tayammum. Because I want to attain Farz namaz in mosque. I don't wanna miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid reason for a sane person to perform tayyamum is the absence of water. Which must be concluded after extensive search. This usually applies only for travelling people who are in a desert and even those must search for water before performing tayammum. As Allah the Almighty says:

> And if you are ill or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women **and find no water**, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and your hands [with it]. Indeed, Allah is ever Pardoning and Forgiving. ([4:43](https://legacy.quran.com/4/43))

So you can't pray unless you've performed ghusl.

Answer (score 1):

No, fear of parents is not a valid reason for tayammum.

*Just keeping it to the point, though there are other things worth talking about here.*